# Why I'm not able to add new key value pair in an associative array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array, key-value

I've a large associative array titled `$data`. For your understanding I'm printing below one element from it.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (

            [id] => 92
            [zip_code] => 07080
            [phone_no] => 7327630062
            [amount] => 
            [currency] => $
            [product_details] => Array
                (
                )

        )
    [1] => Array
        (

            [id] => 93
            [zip_code] => 07081
            [phone_no] => 7327630063
            [amount] => 20
            [currency] => $
            [product_details] => Array
                (
                )

        )
)
```

Now I want to create a new key-value pair in every element of the above associative array titled `$data`. For it I wrote following logic but it's not creating a new key-value pair. Can someone please help me in this regard?

```
foreach($data as $key => $value) {
        if(!empty($value['amount'])) { 
          $value['final_amount'] = $value['amount'] - 2;
        } else 
          $value['final_amount'] = '';        
      }
```

Comment: When doing foreach, PHP creates copies so doing `$value = something` doesn't actually affect the original array

Comment: Try passing `$value` by reference

Comment: In addition, your array appears to be an indexed array of associative arrays. You could do `for ($i=0; $i<count($data); $i++){ $data[$i]['something'] = 'something'; }`

Comment: @Jonathon I agree with your first comment but i don't with second. The foreach loop works

Comment: @Jonathon That would add the overhead of calling the `count()` function on every iteration of the loop.

Comment: Why do you disagree? Doing `foreach($data as $key => $value) { $value['something'] = 'something'; }` does not actually modify `$data`.

Comment: Well yeah it would add that overhead, that's just there for example. I wouldn't normally call count every time, it's just for example

Comment: @Jonathon You can use a `foreach` loop by reference to modify `$data` quite easily; take a look at the answers below.

Comment: @Jonathon That's why it has to be passed by reference `&$value`. This way it **does** modify `$data`

Comment: Yeah I agree, though my suggestion would also work in OP's case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [manual of foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

> In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop
>   precede $value with &. In that case the value will be assigned by
>   reference.

```
foreach($data as $key => &$value)
```

Comment: Manual also contains this warning, which is good practice: `Reference of a $value and the last array element remain even after the foreach loop. It is recommended to destroy it by unset().` In this case, an `unset($value);` statement should be added right below the loop.

Comment: @yitwail: I see that as noise. If the scope of the `$value` isn't clear at first glance, you probably should do some refactoring anyways.

Answer (score 3):

In the `foreach` loop, pass the `$value` by reference by adding an ampersand `&` before the variable name:

```
foreach($data as $key => &$value)
```

This will allow the loop to modify the original `$data` instead of modifying a copy of it.